# Create an array of object using a for loop in coffescript

Tags: coffeescript

Quick question. I can't find the syntax for it (well assuming it exists) for creating an object from a for loop. What is the correct way to do this -

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
objs = (letter[index]:index for letter, index in letters)

#Also tryed..
objs = ({letter[index]:index} for letter, index in letters)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any libraries? If you had Underscore or Lodash, you could `_([e, i] for e, i in letters).object()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coffee> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
coffee> lettersToIndex = {}
{}
coffee> lettersToIndex[letter] = index for letter, index in letters
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
coffee> lettersToIndex
{ a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 }
```

Comment: Python finally added dict comprehensions: `{x: x**2 for x in (2, 4, 6)}`.  Wonder it that's been suggested for `coffeescript`?

Comment: @hpaulj, yep, many times it seems: [#14](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/14), [#77](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/77), [#216](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/216), and [#467](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/467). Not a very useful feature when you have `_.object`.